# How does the android graphics stack work?

Tags: graphics

I know that Android is based on Linux. On a desktop machine, you have an X server which coordinates all the screen activity. Some Linux distributions are working on switching to something other than X (Wayland, or Mir.)

Android doesn't appear to be using X. What does it use instead, and how can I find out more about it?

Comment: https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Android doesn't use X,
although there is a Java implimentation of X made for Android [android-xserver](https://code.google.com/archive/p/android-xserver/).

Instead of X, Android relies on the [SurfaceFlinger and HWC(Hardware Composer)](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-sf-hwc.html),
working with the [BufferQueue](https://source.android.com/devices/graphics/arch-bq-gralloc.html).

[image]